# Quarkus IBM MQ integration on z/OS

Tags: ibm-mq, quarkus

I understand from [this discussion](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/15655) that the IBM MQ integration native image building scenario is covered by [AMQP Connector](https://quarkus.io/guides/amqp-reference).
So far, so good.
However, I have a question about the following scenario in which AMQP Connector doesn't seem a viable solution; in fact we have to integrate with an IBM MQ installed on a z/OS system that doesn't support AMQP protocol.
In this case, have I to give up a priori to make native image building?
Is there an alternative solution in this case to obtain native image build?
I'd like to stress that this is far from a marginal scenario, as IBM Mainframe integration is widely used in certain enterprise and commercial environments.

So far I have in production quarkus microservices without native image build, but I'd like to get this because advantages are too much, moreover this is one of the reasons why I use Quarkus.

Comment: "*Is there an alternative solution in this case to obtain native image build?*" - I am working on a project with a similar setup and as of now, I do not know of a way that is supported in native mode.

Comment: Many enterprises support both mainframe and Unix/Windows queue mangers.   One solution would be to put a Unix/Windows queue manger in front of the mainframe queue manger.

Comment: @JoshMc Very unfortunately I haven't this chance...thanks anyway.